# jQuery ajaxStop in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery plugin that i need to implement ajaxStop to a part of it.
Below is a snippet from my code to show the structure (may not be 100%).

I have shown how my functions are setup as methods in case ajaxStop needs to be implemented as a global function, not sure how I would do that in the current setup.

The problem I'm having is occasionally ajaxStop doesn't get fired even if my ajax response comes back successfully.

1. Can I call ajaxStop from an ajax success callback?
2. What element should I call ajaxStop on
   $().ajaxStop OR $(this).ajaxStop

Thanks very much for any help!

Also perhaps anyone has had trouble with ajaxStop on a Mac?
I just cannot find a solution to why this doesn't work all the time.

I think ajaxStop is not very reliable :(

```
(function($) {

$.fn.doRentalButtons = function($params) {

    var newMethods = {

        startAction:function() {
            var $button = $('a.button');
            $button.click(function(){
                var params = {one:'something',two:'morethings'}
                $(this).doAjax(params);
            });
        },

        doAjax:function(params) {

            $current_button = $(this);
            $container_div = $('#container');

            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'whatever.html',
               data: params,
               success: function(data) {
                   //dostuff

                   var jQueryObject = 
                   if (global_var_hide == 0) {
                       $(this).afterPostRequests($current_button);
                   }
               }()
            });
        },

        afterPostRequests:function($current_button) {
            $().ajaxStop(function(){
               $(this).show();
               $(this).positionDiv($current_button);
            });
        }
    };

    $.each(newMethods, function(i) {
        $.fn[i] = this;
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on this:

I ended up using a counter instead of AjaxStop.
Increment the counter on each button click. And on ajax success / error minus 1 off the counter.

Then I only run my ajax request if the counter == 0.

This seems to work for what I need it for. But this does seem like a temporary solution and there is probably a better way.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.doRentalButtons = function($params) {

    var ajax_busy = 0; 

    var newMethods = {

        startAction:function() {
            var $button = $('a.button');
            $button.click(function(){
                var params = {one:'something',two:'morethings'}
                $(this).doAjax(params);
            });
        },

        doAjax:function(params) {

            $current_button = $(this);
            $container_div = $('#container');

            ajax_busy++;

            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'whatever.html',
               data: params,
               success: function(data) {
                   //dostuff

                   ajax_busy--;

                   var jQueryObject = $('#myDiv');
                   if (ajax_busy == 0) {

                       jQueryObject.show();
                       jQueryObject.positionDiv($current_button);

                   }
               },
               error: function() {
                  ajax_busy--;
               }
            });
        }
    };

    $.each(newMethods, function(i) {
        $.fn[i] = this;
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```